# Dishwasher Still Doesn't Heat After Replacing Heating Element

Tags: dishwasher

Earlier this week my dishwasher (Whirlpool WDT720PADM1) stopped heating while washing.

After watching some YouTube videos, I removed the heating element, tested it with a multimeter and found it had infinite resistance. Indicating a bad heating element.

I ordered a new heating element, installed it, and have run the diagnostic cycle several times, but it's still not heating.

I've also measured the new heating element and it measured ~12 ohms. I've also removed the Thermostat and measured it and it also measured ~1-2 ohms.

When the diagnostic cycle starts it flashes F9 and E1 error codes several times, indicating some draining issue. But unsure if that is related or not.

Considering my original heating element was bad, are there any other steps I can take to determine what is causing my heating problem?

- Has the diagnostic cycle not reset it correctly?
- Should I measure whether the heating element is receiving voltage when running?
- Maybe it’s time to bring in some help?
- Or something else.

When running, the water temperature never gets above 90 degrees F. The heating element itself is always around 72 degrees F.

Comment: Zero Ohms indicates a shortcut, it should read 3-6 Ohms

Comment: For both parts?

Comment: I remeasured resistance for both parts, ~12 ohms for the new heating element and ~1-2 ohms for the thermostat. I think I just wasn't paying close attention the first time measuring them.

Comment: It wont start heating until you solve the draining issue

Answer (score 1):

> 9-1 or F9E1
>
> Electronic control board can't detect the position of the diverter disc Check/Repair
>
> The diverter motor positions the disc that directs the water through the lower spray arm or the upper spray arm. The diverter motor also monitors the position of the diverter disc and sends position signals to the electronic control board. Unplug the dishwasher to disconnect power and check the wiring going to the diverter motor. Reconnect any loose wires or replace the wire harness if damaged. If the wiring is intact, replace the diverter motor because it isn't sending position signals to the electronic control board.

Source: [Sears Parts Direct](https://www.searspartsdirect.com/diy/error-codes/dishwasher-repair/1234583/whirlpool-he-dishwasher/1198)

Comment: I _think_ I've reformatted this to indicate that it's a direct quote from the Sears Parts Direct website (no, I didn't click the link). Please roll back if I got it wrong, then provide some additional clarification.